# Meaning of an idiomatic sentence

Tags: meaning, idiom-meaning

Please help me understand this sentence:

> Out of the back of the store came his dog running down the aisle followed by five little puppies.

I also don't understand the structure of the sentence. I'm sorry about my grammar!

Comment: Would it be easier if we changed the word order to *His dog came running out of the back of the store, down the aisle, followed by five little puppies*?

Answer (score 2):

Allow me to break down this sentence's structure:

On the first level (the main clause):

- Adverbial complement denoting the place or position: *Out of the back
  of the store*
- Predicate: *came*
- Subject: his dog
- Adverbial complement denoting the manner: *running down the aisle*
- Another adverbial complement: *followed by five little puppies*

Both adverbial complements modify the verb *came* and give you extra information about *where from* (the back of the store) and *how* (running down the aisle + followed by five little puppies) the dog came.

That is the structure of the *main clause*. However, there is also a subclause as you might have noticed. This subclause only counts as **one** function within the main clause, but it can be broken down on its own level into functions. The phrase *followed by five little puppies* is a non-finite subclause and can be broken down like so:

- Subject: *his dog*
- Predicate: *followed*
- By-agent: *by five little puppies*

Though *his dog* is not actually found within the subclause, it does act as the subject of it. Subclauses often have the word that they're attached to as their subject. Let me illustrate this with a finite subclause:

> That is the man *who* **I saw yesterday**.

The word *who* here acts as the subject of the subclause *I saw yesterday*.

In your sentence, there is no word like *who* connecting the subclause to the main clause, since we're dealing with a **non-finite** subclause here:

> ... *his dog* ... **followed by five little puppies**.

The finite version would look like this:

> ...his dog *that* **was followed by five little puppies**.